# How search and replace with Textwrangler xml tag ? with grep?

Tags: regex, search, replace, grep, textwrangler

For example, i try to search and delete in an XML file all node wp:postmeta who has different content

```
    <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[2]]></wp:meta_value>
    </wp:postmeta>
```

I'll try first something like : `<wp:postmeta>*</wp:postmeta>` thinking that it will return all the node. But it doesn't work.
What is the methodology for that sort of search ?
Thx

Comment: it would help if you post some input,expected output and your attempts .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<wp:postmeta>[\s\S]*?</wp:postmeta>
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sA8iT4/2

Comment: I works with only on node. And I want to delete all the tag <wp:postmeta>in my long long file...

Comment: @jcbaudot You need to use `g` or `global` flag for that.Apply the flag

Comment: Thank you. I'll try, but it only work when I delete the new line escape see here : http://regex101.com/r/sA8iT4/1 PS.Regex is difficult to learn..

Comment: Amazing ! It's magic. Now I try to understand the regex for next time. Thank you !